# Getting an entirely white screen upon return from Amazon

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, amazon-web-services

I am building a hybrid app using Apache Cordova and Amazon's MWS. Everything works fine so far from my desktop browser. However, when I attempt to run the app on my phone, I get a blank white screen as soon as I submit my username and password to Amazon.

Here is the link to my app as a website:

https://mytrafficman.net/app/android/

This is the page that is supposed to be returned after entering your username and password (loads fine from desktop):

https://mytrafficman.net/app/android/ticket.html

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you whitelisted the domain in your config? http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: You aren't giving a lot to go on really. Can you explain more what you are doing? Are you connecting to the remote server only and viewing that in the inappbrowser? Can you debug on your device and check console output?

Comment: I can check console output? That would be so handy!

Comment: If you install the Android SDK you will get the ADB utilities, activate USB debugging on your phone - connect it to your computer and run "adb logcat" and you will see the console output on your computer

Comment: The console log is a hot mess of TMI. It also scrolls by really really fast.